# How to check if it is a valid git repo

Tags: git

I have a git repo B inside a git repo A. When I deleted .git/refs/ in repo B. The tag name of repo B immediately changed to repo A's branch name. It seems like Git think repo B is just a part of repo A.

Then when I check status (git status) in repo B, it shows that git status

> fatal: 'b/.git' not recognized as a git repository

I read the git cookbook, it said that .git/HEAD is used to detect if it is a valid git. In my situation, .git/HEAD is still existed but .git/refs/ . Result is that repo B is not recognized as a git repo.

Anyone can help me to figure out how to check if a folder is a valid git ? what files or folders existence I need to be checked in the .git/ to make sure that it is a valid git ?

Comment: Why not use `git status` for that then?

Comment: @zerkms I did after deleted .git/refs/ . And it turned out result that repo B is not recognized as a git repository anymore. I guess .git/refs/ is crucial element.

Comment: It is crucial as that's how git knows which branch points to which commit. It's like deleting master and then wondering why you can't commit.

Comment: @thp doesn't it answer your question? "Anyone can help me to figure out how to check if a folder is a valid git ?" --- use `git status`

Comment: One valuable lesson here is: don't go modifying the internal files of some program and expect the program to keep working. :-) It's OK to experiment, of course, just be aware of these things. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights

Comment: @torek Thank you for your comment. Normally I don't modify the internal files. Actually this situation is happening in my workplace. I am trying to figure out how to make sure repo B is a valid repo, as my expectation in case someone else modify or "experience" with internal files without noticing me.

Comment: @zerkms yes I did try. But the output is not my expectation. The folder repo B is a release so normally I don't modify or touch it. So if I use git status to check repo B, the output should be up-to-date, nothing change or modify. After I deleted .git/refs/ in repo B and use git status to check repo B again, the output shows that repo B is dirty, and show me the list of modified files and folders in repo A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple different questions you can ask here, each of which gets a *different answer*.  For instance:

- Given that I am in some working directory (`pwd` will print some path), how can I tell if I am in a Git work-tree?  That is, will various Git commands work?

  The answer to that is: try the various Git commands, and see if they work.  Note that `git rev-parse` has had a built in test, `--is-inside-work-tree`, since Git version 1.5.3 (released way back in 2007).  But note that if `$GIT_WORK_TREE` is set in the environment, that path is used for the test, rather than the path that `pwd` will print.

  **When a Git command succeeds, it does what the documentation says it does and in most cases, will exit zero for success.**  So you can use `if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree; then ...; fi` in POSIX-compatible shells.  When this `git rev-parse` command *fails*, it prints an error message to its standard error and exits non-zero, which skips the `then ...` part.  To suppress the error message, you can use `2> /dev/null` in these same POSIX shells.
- Given that I am in some working directory, how can I tell if I am in the underlying `.git` repository?

  See above but substitute `--is-inside-git-dir` for `--is-inside-work-tree`, and note that `$GIT_DIR` is the name of the environment variable that Git uses instead of the result of `pwd` here.
- Given that some working directory *should have been* a Git directory, but some event—power failure, file system corruption, or the like—has damaged it and now Git says it is *not* a Git directory, what could be wrong?

  Here, many things could be wrong.  However, the *fast* test that Git runs consists of:

  - locate the prospective Git directory (`$GIT_DIR` or `.git` or `../.git` or whatever);
  - check for the `HEAD` file;
  - check that `refs/` exists; and
  - check that `objects/` exists.

  These last two steps are skipped if `$GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` is set in the environment and points to an existing directory.  The code that implements all of this is in [setup.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad05a3d8e5a6a06443836b5e40434262d992889a/setup.c#L300-L349).
- Given that I am in some working directory, how does Git find the `.git` directory and/or the work-tree?

  See above about `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` overrides.  If those are *not* set, and you have not used `git --git-dir` or `git --work-tree` (which set them for the duration of the one `git` command), Git starts by examining the *current directory*—the one you are in, that `pwd` prints—and if that is not a Git directory, Git tries climbing "up" one level in the file-system tree by moving to `..`.  For instance, if you are in `/home/you/path/to/dir`, that is the first place Git looks.  If that fails, Git goes on to look in `/home/you/path/to`, then `/home/you/path`, then `/home/you`, then `/home`, then just `/`.

  This process of climbing up the file system tree to the root<sup>1</sup> will automatically *stop* if and when Git detects, in some operating-system dependent manner, that it is crossing an (OS-defined) *mount point*.  To prevent Git from stopping at mount points, you can set the environment variable `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` to any value.

---

<sup>1</sup>Many computer scientists / informatics students like to draw their trees upside down, with the leaves on or buried in the ground, and the roots sticking up into the air.  (And, Linus Torvalds is a CS/informatics guy.) :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems like the third point is what I need

Comment: How can I use `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` to check till `/home/you`?

Comment: @alper: Just set the env var to some nonempty string. The usual standard nonempty strings here are "true" or "yes". How you set this variable depends on which shell you're using.